# Discord.js: Cannot read property "cache" of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm currently coding a discord bot with discord.js. I'm trying to get a specific channel from a specific guild by id to then write messages into. I found this solution on grepper but when running I get the error "Cannot read the property 'cache' of undefinded" But why is channels undefined? The discord.js documentation lists channel as a property of guild: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild. Anyone know why this is happening?

```js
client.guilds.fetch(guildID).channels.cache.get(channelID)
```

Comment: What version of Discord are you running?

Comment: Discord.js version 12.3.1

Comment: When is that piece of code run? ( any event or ?=)

Comment: Inside of the client.on("ready", () => { ... }) event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`client.guilds.fetch(guildID)` is a promise, what you would need is:

`client.guilds.fetch(guildID).then(guild => guild.channels.cache.get(channelID).send('HI!'))`

of if you wanna go 100% secure

```
client.guilds.fetch(guildID)
    .then(guild => 
        guild.channels.fetch(channelID)
            .then(channel => 
                 channel.send('HI!')
));
```

Comment: Channels are cached alongside guilds, so fetching the channel is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

The most easy and short way to do this is

```
const channel = client.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL-ID")
channel.send("Hello")
```