# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

i was coding my logs on my discord bot, but when i trying to upload an image in the server, console give me this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')`

Here's my code:

`

```
const { Events } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: Events.MessageCreate,
    execute(client, msg) {
        //if (msg.author.bot) return;
        const channel = client.channels.cache.get('1035536575200768010');
        if (msg.attachments) {
            const attachment = msg.attachments;
            const len = attachment.toJSON().length;
            for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                let object = attachment.toJSON()[i]
                channel.send(`${msg.author.username} just sent image at ${msg.author.channelId}`)
            }
        }
        else channel.send(msg.content)
    }
}
```

`

I think i got a problem with this line:

`const channel = client.channels.cache.get('1035536575200768010');`

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65132403/discord-js-cannot-read-property-cache-of-undefined

Comment: You should do some debugging first. Checking/logging the value of `client.channels` would be a great start.

Comment: Can you show your event handler? A problem we see quite often here is that the arguments passed into the command is in the wrong order

Comment: Here's my event handler
`const eventsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'events');
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync(eventsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
 const filePath = path.join(eventsPath, file);
 const event = require(filePath);
 if (event.once) {
  client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
 } else if (event.name == 'messageCreate') {
  client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
 } else {
  client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
 }

}`

Comment: I knew the problem, it's Event.MessageCreate return Message not Client.